# How to change mysql DB to convert saved text to readable version of UTF-8

Tags: mysql, database

I have some problem with my mysql database. I need to use proper mysql server configuration. My mysql configuration has

```
init-connect='SET NAMES latin2'
```

my tables are utf8_general_ci

and everything stored by PHP scripts using UTF-8 are unreadable in database like:

```
Ĺwietnie
```

but it should be

```
świetnie
```

I can use this DB from php and read it like it should be. BUT when remove ini-connect from my.cnf - mysql configuration everything is unreadable.

I can manually export DB and convert it with iconv

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t latin2 in.txt > out.txt
```

then i have readable Polish characters and i can import this DB and use with mysql configuration.

My question is - how to use my.cnf without

```
init-connect='SET NAMES latin2'
```

and convert databases to readable Polish characters

Comment: i don't see, why it is bad that you tell every connection, that it has to use Latin2 as character set, but you can convert your database to uto 8 like described here https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/Converting_your_MySQL_database_to_UTF8 and be done with it

Comment: This is bad bc im using UTF-8 on my php and yes it stored in UTF-8 in BD but is unreadable in DB and some scripts cannot convert this DB to proper utf-8 and get unreadable text.
So my method using iconv is some like mysqldump or sed.

Comment: I was used latin2 before, now my php scripts and all web is in UTF8 so now i stored UTF8 characters by ini-connect which is latin2 so text are unreadable.

Comment: The system described should work, so give it a try. You first make a sqldumb in the original configuration, so everything should be readable in the sql file, afterwards you import evrything back but this time every is stored in utf8 and the etxt should still be readable.

Comment: so mysqldumb every DB and then change on my.cnf [mysqld] and remove init-connect='SET NAMES latin2' and then import every DB again?

Comment: that are only variables for mysql that ypu can change at runtime, like the link shows

Comment: pls tell me why when i removed from my.cnf init-connect='SET NAMES latin2' and DB has text in UTF8 coded i have to use on my php scripts @ini_set ( 'default_charset', 'utf-8' );
header ( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' ); otherway characters on web are unreadable. Thats why i want everything to change like it should be.

Comment: charactersets and encoding is hard. your ś is in utf8 https://graphemica.com/%C5%9B and a completely differnt code in https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-2 , but you saved is as 8859-2 bits in utf 8 where is has teh same value, but refers to another character

Comment: so its mess up then, hm. How to fix that? I think is coinnected to this mysqld variable init-connect hm. For example vacation plugin to read from this i need to change SET CHARACTER SET latin2; then it works :) but its saved in UTF8. BIG mess up :) I think i have to all DB export and change from UTF8 to Latin2 to readable characters and then use mysqld without init-connect. Then it soulg all work as should be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198767/discussion-between-kenny-and-nbk).